# app/code doesnot exist

Tags: magento2

https://github.com/magento/magento2/tree/develop/app/code/Magento

i downnloaded `Magento-CE-2.1.1_sample_data-2016-08-29-06-45-34.tar.gz`

and it doesnot have also app/code inside

also directory under apache is same

```
/var/www/html/magento2/app$ ls
autoload.php  bootstrap.php  design  etc  functions.php
```

here

https://community.magento.com/t5/Building-Extensions/Display-template-in-Admin-Module-of-Magento/td-p/28525

he says he puts his code under app/code  but i cant put? i try to create an admin entry.

How can i do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you have a fresh installation of Magento 2 there is no app/code folder. You have to create it if you need to add a new local module.

Comment: I downloaded from website.If i dont see all code, how can i create some module? i now downloaded fromgithub code. put to war/www and then run localhost(magento/esetup but di not work but now in root i did composer insstall. i hope it works.  becase normaly it asks for a lt of things here http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/install-gde/prereq/dev_install.html

Comment: Don't install from Github. It's only going to cause problems later. When they build Magento for release, they move all of their official code from app/code/Magento to vendor/magento. This is completely intentional.

Comment: BUt ,in all tutoarials, they show app/code directory? how can i find there?